# Permisos ubicación ios “:// le gustaría usar su ubicación actual”

Tags: ionic, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

quiero cambiar el nombre en el diálogo que me muestra Ios > **Ionic v5**. el texto dice:

“:// Le gustaría usar su ubicación actual”

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el `Info.Plis`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

también ¿Por qué se muestra este nombre de la aplicación ://?

plugins relevantes:

```
cordova-plugin-background-geolocation 3.1.0 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.8.0 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-firebasex 10.2.0 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.1.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 5.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.4.1 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 6.0.3 "SocialSharing"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 6.0.4 "Diagnostic"
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 5.0.6 "Launch Navigator"
```

Sé que esta alerta es requerida por ios. Pero solo quiero cambiar el texto y no obtengo resultados con éxito

Ya agregué tambíen en el Info.plis las siguientes claves:

- **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**
- **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**
- **NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription**
- **NSLocationUsageDescription**

y sigo sin obtener el resultado esperado

Cualquier ayuda gracias!!

Comment: Se supone que ahí va el nombre de tu App. Cómo tienes el `Bundle display name` en el archivo `info.plist`?.

Comment: El `Bundle display name` ya tiene el nombre del app

Comment: Sería útil que mostraras el archivo que te comentan para que quienes intentan responder no deban adivinar dónde puede estar el error

Comment: En `Bundle name` tengo `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`, puedes intentar con ese cambio que es lo único diferente que veo.

Answer (score 0):

Pues en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312167/would-like-to-use-your-current-location) dicen que puede ser un bug en WKWebView. Y que usando el plugin [Geolocation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/geolocation) evitas este problema.

Comment: ya estoy usando `cordova-plugin-geolocation` pero sigo recibiendo la misma alerta (aunque info.plist tiene todas las llaves mencionadas), y nunca uso `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`